# Как сделать, чтобы инпут был сразу активным без клика на него?

Tags: html

Мне нужно, чтобы инпут был все время активным. Я добавил атрибут  autofocus, но инпут активизируется только при клике. Буду рад любой подсказке!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тег input, атрибут autofocus</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="handler.php">
   <p>Поиск по сайту</p>
   <p><input type="search" name="s" >
   <input autofocus type="submit" value="Искать"></p>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <body onload="document.nameOfForm.nameOfField.focus();">
 Только тут надо имя форме дать, а nameoffield это s в вашем случае

Comment: Ну а в Вашем случае просто autofocus не у того input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[name="s"]')
setTimeout(_ => input.focus(), 0)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тег input, атрибут autofocus</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="handler.php">
   <p>Поиск по сайту</p>
   <p><input type="search" name="s" >
   <input autofocus type="submit" value="Искать"></p>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тег input, атрибут autofocus</title>
 </head>
 <body onload="document.form1.field1.focus();">
  <form action="handler.php" name="form1">
   <p>Поиск по сайту</p>
   <p><input autofocus type="search" name="field1" >
   <input  type="submit" value="Искать"></p>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```